# Duplicate jar entry

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, android-r8

I'm trying to obfuscate my code and make a release build but when i do i'm getting a Duplicate Jar entry with proguard or Program type already present when using R8. The class it's complaining about I overrode by specifiying the class in it's classpath so i could override a library class.

Say the library has a class, com.example.A. I put the class path com.example in my project and have a class called A with the same signature but changed the behavior a little bit for performance logging that I thought would be a good addition. Now the code won't compile when creating a release build but it works as expected on debug builds overriding the library class.

Anyone experience this and have suggestions on how I can keep my overriden class? All documentation online specifies getting rid of the offending duplicates instead of having some kind of force resolution path.